# Нужно ли выделять запятыми слова "по заданию..."?

Tags: пунктуация

Объединением таким-то, по заданию такого-то, разработана линия транспортировки стружки...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если "такое-то" объединение и "такое-то" лицо (или кто оно там) – так вот, если их наименования не слишком длинные, то я бы не обособлял. Если длинные, то обособил бы.

Comment: Значит обособление все же возможно... Но там названия не слишком длинные, так что, видимо, можно обойтись без запятых.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, обособление не требуется.

Это неоднородные члены предложения, входящие в основное сообщение. При обособлении мы получим значение уточнения, которое вряд ли соответствует семантике предложения.